# Getting error in LINQ Expression or converting service to client simple mapping

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list, c#-4.0

Getting this error

```
"System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[Person.Models.IProfession,System.String]"
```

Code is below: I am trying to have a collection of result. Service returns me collection I think and I need to iterate through and store as a list which will have that collection. Please help me

```
public class ProfessionResult
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ID{ get; set; }
}

public List<ProfessionResult> ProfessionResults
{
    get
    {
        var professionResults = new List<ProfessionResult>();

        professionResults.Add(new ProfessionResult()
        {
            Name = People?.Where(p => p.IsSelected)
                .Select(c => c.ProfessionResults.Select(n => n.Name))
                .ToString() ?? null,
            ID = People?.Where(p => p.IsSelected)
                .Select(c => c.ProfessionResults.Select(i => i.ID))
                .ToString() ?? null
        });

        return professionResults;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the full error, you only posted a partial error. Also, what line does the error occur on?

Comment: @SledgeHammer: Thank you for your concern, I am not getting anything in the UI while I see using dev tools, and I see this underneath each property "System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[Person.Models.IProfession,System.String]"

Comment: Also, its the same while I debugged the code above un the return professionResults line its what was present for both properties

Answer (score 0):

A basic google search on your partial error message revealed this post:
[Linq query on Xdocument returns "System.linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator'2[system.XML.Linq.Xelement,System.String]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26043472/linq-query-on-xdocument-returns-system-linq-enumerablewhereselectenumerableite)

According to it,

> Yes, that's because you've calling ToString() directly on a query for
>   your second and third values.
>
> Basically, don't call ToString() on queries. If you want a single
>   value, use Single(), First() etc. If you want multiple values, iterate
>   over them and do what you want with each of them in turn - or join
>   them together in some appropriate fashion.

Which means you will have to store the values as their initial format and not use `ToString()` on them **inside** the linq query.

*Edit**

For example, you could try:

```
Name = People?.Where(p => p.IsSelected).Select(c => c.ProfessionResults.Select(n => n.Name)).Single().ToString() ?? null,
ID = People?.Where(p => p.IsSelected).Select(c => c.ProfessionResults.Select( i => i.ID)).Single().ToString() ?? null
```

But only if you know **for sure** that you will return a single unique record with `p => p.IsSelected` every time.

I haven't tested it, so let me know if it works.

Comment: Keyur, thank you, I did the same and found skeet's answer, but not sure if I implement that correctly. Can you please guide me incorporating that correctly in my code above please

Comment: Edited my answer to include code relevant to your case. Kindly test it out and let me know if it works.

Comment: Keyur, sure thank you, please give me some moments, I am asked to work on some other priority task for an hour now :( Surely will update you in a while